# Shut down message ... blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0

Tags: kde, manjaro, shutdown

After updating two systems (one desktop and one laptop), when I shut down the computers I see several messages like this …

```
# blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 0 op 0x1
```

**My software:**
Manjaro
KDE Plasma Version 5.20.4
KDE Frameworks Version 5.77.0
Qt Version 5.15.2
Kernel Version 5.10.2-2

**My hardware:**
Processor 4xIntel Core i7x6500 CPU @ 2.50Ghz
Memory 16 GiB RAM
Graphics Mesa Intel HD Graphics 520
SSD WDC 250 GiB
HDD 1TB

**Research:**
I've seen several posts about problems like this, all related to floppy, but that's not my case.
If I type ...

```
lsmod | grep -i floppy
```

the answer is nothing.
I tried the blacklist just in case, but as I said that's not it.
I've also checked if I have the correct UUID in fstab and they're all fine.
I guess the problem is not related to fstab because I have the same problem with 2 very different computers.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot in advance!

**lsblk ...**

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   3,6T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   3,6T  0 part /htpc
sdb           8:16   0  12,7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0  12,7T  0 part /hdd1
sdc           8:32   0  10,9T  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   0  10,9T  0 part /hdd2
sdd           8:48   0   3,6T  0 disk 
└─sdd1        8:49   0   3,6T  0 part /hdd3
sde           8:64   1 119,5G  0 disk 
└─sde1        8:65   1 119,5G  0 part /run/media/knight/SAMSUNG
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   640M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    32G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    64G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0    32G  0 part /adds
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 337,1G  0 part /apps
```

**losetup --list ...**

returns nothing at all.

I realized the problem happens only when I open a VeraCrypt volume.